# QImage ограничения размера

Tags: qt, qimage

При формировании изображения `QImage` формата `Format::FormatMono` размером больше чем 32767х32767, оно формируется, однако, при попытке отрисовать что-то на этом изображении за рамками вышеупомянутой границы, все обрезается. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть сверху, размер изображения 30000х80000, однако при превышении границы всё обрезается.

компилятор mingw32, ОС win7 64.
Пример кода:

```
QImage* example_img= new QImage(40000,40000,QImage::Format_Mono);
QPainter painter_for_text(example_img);
QPen pen_for_text;
pen_for_text.setColor(QColor(255,255,255,255));
QFont font = painter_for_text.font();
font.setPixelSize(8000);

painter_for_text.setFont(font);
painter_for_text.setPen(pen_for_text);

painter_for_text.drawText(20000,20000,QString("HELLO,HELLO,HELLO"));
QImageWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("tiff");
QString filename_save = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                         tr("Save tiff"), ".",
                                                         tr("tiff files (*.tiff)"));
writer.setFileName(filename_save);
writer.write(*example_img);
```

Comment: Давайте код в студию. Изображение можно внедрить через base64-кодирование. И второй момент - какова разрядность цели сборки и целевая ОС?

Comment: @Majestio, обновил

Comment: в коде - ни одной проверки! Особенно после new. Попробуйте проверки. Чуйка подсказывает на то, что 32-х разрядная ОС не тянет эту картинку.

Comment: @Majestio, очень даже тянет, картинка ведь создается, но вот при нанесении на неё чего-либо, все , что оказывается за границей 32767 - обрезается.

Comment: @Majestio, и ОС 64 разрядная, я же написал, а вот собираю mingw32

Comment: А как понимать коммент выше "Разрядность сборки 32"???

Comment: @Majestio, описался, прошу прощения. ради интереса попробовал msvc64, изменений нет.

Comment: Хм ... Сформируйте проект, заверните в архив, и выкиньте на яндекс.диск, к примеру. Чисто поиграться. Иначе - гадать накладно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что растеризатор у Qt урезанный, и работать с изображениями, чьи размеры превышают short - нельзя.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#limitations

> If you are using coordinates with Qt's raster-based paint engine, it
>   is important to note that, while coordinates greater than +/- 32767 can
>   be used, any painting performed with coordinates outside this range is
>   not guaranteed to be shown; the drawing may be clipped. This is due to
>   the use of short int in the implementation.

Тут написано, что рисование МОЖЕТ быть обрезано, однако оно будет обрезано всегда, т.к исходниках можно увидеть следующее:

```
// This limitations comes from qgrayraster.c. Any higher and
// rasterization of shapes will produce incorrect results.
const int QT_RASTER_COORD_LIMIT = 32767;
```